# How to export getter in ES6 module system

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

Is it possible to export getter in import/export module system?

```
export getter $topbar(){ return $('.topbar') }
```

How can it be implemented?

edited:

So while I was asking the question I learned that every variable exported as `by ref` so any exported variable act as getter and expose fresh value each time value as checked.

it means changing the variable value in the module will change the value in every imported module

example:

```
export const topbar
```

Comment: How would you expect to use it? Just as a variable which when evaluated calls your getter callback? I don't think it is possible.

Comment: it does not look like a duplicate. the other question asks about Exporting module and I ask for `exporting getter`. my question is simple and the other question is far complicated

Comment: @perymimon I'm not sure how you would want to export "a getter". A getter is always part of an object. Do you just want to export the getter function?

Comment: by say getter I mean something that acts like a variable but returns fresh value every time we ask for the value even for primitive value.  it better if we have the ability to calculate the value just on demand.

Comment: I was looking to do that as well. I guess Javascript doesn't support the syntax yet. It would be useful to avoid refactors.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to export getter in import/export module system?

It is not possible. ES6 modules can't export getters because they don't even export values. ES6 module syntax *exposes* a local variable so that it can be accessed from outside the module, but it never even looks at the value.

That means that the same way you can't have a getter for an arbitrary variable, you also can't have a getter for an export.

The only option is to export a function that the library user would need to call.

Comment: soo.. expose variable is almost the same as exposing getter that returns the current value... interesting

Comment: Yes, so you could export a variable and reassigning it will affect the places that import it too. If the topbar element is actually going to change though, you'd be export a function so that way users of your code know to expect it to change. Most people would expect an exported variable to stay constant I think.

Comment: it will be constant when it initializes but export things come before everything else so ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying.

Answer (score -8):

Duplicate of [ES6 - Exporting module with a getter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176036/es6-exporting-module-with-a-getter).

Just do like this:

```
export function $topbar() { return $('.topbar') }
```

Or:

```
export const $topbar = () => $('.topbar');
```

Comment: but then every use of that value need to use punctuation brackets `$topbar().append(...)` everywhere instead of `$topbar.append`

Comment: @perymimon ok. Try this one - `const $topbar = $('.topbar');
export $topbar;`.

Comment: ok, but then `$topbar` evaluated just one. and maybe not it the right time. instead of evaluated on the use and return every time the right value (not mention for memory leak because the hard reference)